# "I can not attend to something" meaning "I'm free not to attend to something"?

Tags: grammar

When I say "*I cannot attend to it*" it sounds like I'm saying "*I'm not able to attend to it*", while what I want to express is that I'm capable of doing it, but I just don't need to.

In Slavic languages it's resolved by changing the negation particle position: *[negation] [can] [do something]* vs. *[can] [negation] [do something]*. In the first case I negate "*can*", while in the second I negate the "*do*" verb.

How to achieve the same in English and not be ambiguous?

Comment: "I don't need to X" or "I'm not required to X".

Comment: Yes. 'Cannot' forces the 'not able to' reading, while 'I can not attend to it.' is inherently ambiguous between 'I [can not] attend to it.' and 'I can [not attend] to it.' To be fair, the latter reading is artificial-sounding and the default is as you indicate (and would almost always be spelled, and certainly pronounced) 'cannot'. Myles has the answer as to how to ensure the second sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English this is often achieved by using the opposite verb.  In this sentence you could say "I'm free to avoid something" or "I'm free to skip something".