# “Can I not read it”?

Tags: questions, negation, modal-verbs

If a person is asking about permission *not* to read something, he doesn't want to read it and asks not to read it. Can we use the phrase “Can I not read it”? Is it correct?

Comment: The meaning might be clear when *spoken* with intonation, but it is ambiguous when written.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used it in speaking. But, can you provide better alternative? Thank you!

Comment: "Do you mind if I don't read it?"

Comment: Thank you! It helped me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I can not attend to something" meaning "I'm free not to attend to something"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203766/i-can-not-attend-to-something-meaning-im-free-not-to-attend-to-something)

Comment: Kind of, but it doesn't my question fully.)

Comment: The point is that "Can I not read it?" (unless spoken with a particular intonation) is a formal way of asking "Can't I read it" (Am I not allowed to?)